# Нужна ли точка в конце заголовка?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли ставить точку после слов **"Классная работа", "Домашняя работа", "Диктант", "Упражнение"** и т.д.?
На какой источник можно сослаться?

Comment: С заголовками все понятно меня интересуют фразы "классная работа, домашняя работа, диктант, упражнение", которые используются при оформлении  письменных работ в школе. В данных предложениях (фразах)необходимо ставить точку?

Comment: Это и есть заголовки.

Comment: Отлично. Спасибо за статью и комментарии. Скажите пожалуйста, надо ли ставить точку в конце, если заголовок состоит из двух предложений?

Comment: В рукописях всегда надо. Не надо — в заголовках статей. И не надо задавать вопросы и комментировать ответы в окне «Задать вопрос»!

Answer (score 2):

> Нужно ли ставить точки после слов "классная работа", "домашняя
>   работа", "диктант", "упражнение" и т.д.

Вот как ответила на подобный вопрос [Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

============================================

Так же когда-то отвечали на вопрос о точках и Розенталь с Добромысловым в одной из своих книг:

> Школьников необходимо приучать ставить точки после заглавий.

**P.S.**

Кстати, до недавнего времени в школьных учебниках по русскому языку точки после заголовков обычно ставились.

Answer (score 2):

```
     На какой источник можно сослаться?
```

На документ "Единый орфографический режим ведения школьной документации": http://do.gendocs.ru/docs/index-190901.html#5133889

В начальной школе всё строго — с точками, потому что дети только учатся видеть предложение и оформлять его. Потом просто соблюдается единство требований в младшем и среднем звене. В старших классах дети узнают о том, что точка после названий не ставится. И пошёл разноброд — кто ставит, кто не ставит. Договорились, что методический совет школы создаёт *Положение о едином орфографическом режиме*, и его исполняют все в этой школе.
До 1933 года ставили точки  не только в школе, — везде. Сравните правила в двух близких по времени выхода в свет справочниках:
*«После заголовка и подзаголовков ставить обязательно точку»* (Служивов Л. И. Справочник корректора. Практическое руководство для корректора, наборщика, редактора и автора. М., 1932. С. 123);
*«Так как в наших газетах принято давать заголовки без заключительных точек, корректор должен позаботиться о том, чтобы случайно набранные точки были удалены уже в первой корректуре»* (Технико-орфографический словарь-справочник. Под ред. Н. Филиппова. Л., 1933. С. 20).

В первом справочнике читаем:
Предисловие.
Оглавление.

Тогда как во втором соответственно находим:
От редактора
От составителей
Но, по-видимому, оформление заголовка без точки — здесь дело еще новое: недаром же во втором справочнике внимание корректора направляется на «удаление» «случайно набранных точек»!

Вот документ: http://nsportal.ru/nachalnaya-shkola/materialy-mo/2012/08/04/edinyy-orfograficheskiy-rezhim-v-nachalnoy-shkole

Comment: *В начальной школе всё строго - с точками, потому что дети только учатся видеть предложение и оформлять его, потом просто соблюдается единство требований в младшем и среднем звене.* - Бедные детишки. По сути их приучают к тому, что все, чему учат в школе - неправильно. Но меня больше поразил сам документ - шедевр советского бюрократического искусства.

Answer (score 1):

Какая глупость - приучать  в школе ставить точки в заголовках (снижением оценок), а потом отучать, потому что по правилам делопроизводства НЕ ставятся точки в заголовках документов. Я  с этим сама столкнулась в свое время, переучиваться было непросто. Если нет единства (а его нет!), так давайте не будем чморить детей!

Comment: Светлана, двумя руками поддерживаю Вас, но только что такое "чморить"?))

Answer (score 0):

В конце заголовков (вы же про них спрашиваете?) точка не ставится. Откройте любую газету, например.

Comment: Заголовок в газете не отделяется от сообщения точкой, но выделяется. Шрифтом, размером, толщиной, разрядкой, цветом и пр.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что большого ума люди в 1933-ем перестали считать заголовок предложением, считая его "именованием". Самое удивительное в том, что единого толкового определения предложения у филологов нет до сих пор. Действительно, а зачем?

Вот, что даёт Вики, например: "Предложе́ние (в языке) — это единица языка, которая представляет собой грамматически организованное соединение слов (или слово), обладающее смысловой и интонационной законченностью. С точки зрения пунктуации, предложение как законченная единица речи оформляется в конце точкой, восклицательным или вопросительным знаками — или многоточием. Также предложение является синонимом «фразы»".

Это никак не противоречит тому, что мы встречаем в заголовках. И уже тем более, фраза в заголовке — норма. Но. Дело в том, что по нормам русского языка необходимо ставить после любого предложения точку или иной знак препинания, заканчивающий его так же, как начинает заглавная буква.
Теперь попробуй объяснить ребёнку, что есть на свете такие люди, как типографы, которые любят экономить на краске, не печатая точки где только можно: в букве Ё, в конце заголовков... По-другому эту нарочную путаницу логически не распутать.
То же самое касается и других определений предложения, которые встречаются у разных авторов. Другими словами, отсутствие точки после заголовка — это так принято сейчас, но принято вопреки здравому смыслу (другие знаки-то ставят...) и сегодняшним лингвистическим определениям понятия "предложение в русском языке".

Comment: Много слов ни о чем. А можно без лишних эмоций изложить сухой остаток из вашего ответа?

Comment: Если кому трудно понять смысл в прошлом ответе или просто лень читать исторические справки, то вот сухой остаток: в лингвистике на данный момент отсутствует единое чёткое определение понятия "предложения", а из тех, что есть, следует признать ошибочным написание заголовка без точки на конце. Потому что "именование" нигде не отделяется от "предложения" в независимую структуру.

Comment: И ещё для тех, кто минусует - если действительно нет согласия, то почему бы не объяснить, где именно? Детского страха минусов нет, есть взрослый интерес к теме. Например, жду ссылок на определения "именования" и, может, вариантов для "предложение"...

Comment: Экономят пиксели на моём мониторе.